# Angular 2 SEO with Pre-Render.io

Tags: angular, prerender

Basically I want to use Pre-Render.io for my Angular 2 application and I am new to it, I have gone through the [Doc](https://prerender.io/documentation/test-it) of Pre-Render.io But I only able to get this Pre-Render.io to work with Angular 1, I am unable to get it work with Angular 2, I am not getting any error messages also. It will be very helpful if I get any other doc or video tutorials or example for how to use Pre-Render.io with Angular 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really an angular question because you don't have to do anything with your angular app in order for it to work. Only a simple metatag needs to be added to the index file.

Follow these steps:

- Step 1

Add this to your angular app:

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

- Step 2

Run `npm install prerender-node --save` in your node project (or whatever you're using)

- Step 3

Add this to your server (or equivalent if you're not using node):

```
app.use(require('prerender-node'));
```

- Step 4

Configurate nginx or whatever you're using to redirect the crawlers to your fragmented site. This is outside of my knowledge base however so any questions regarding this should be opened as a new question if you're unsure about how to do it.

Comment: sorry, I didn't get step 3 n 4... can you please explain it

Comment: Step 3: Add that line to your `server.js` file (if using node, if not you have to look at the other examples in their docs). Step 4: I can't explain this further I'm afraid. You have to make sure that traffic that enters your site are forwarded to the real site, while crawlers are redirected to the fragmented site. What I mean by fragmented site is the site which prerender has rendered.

Comment: Thank you for your help, try will try it.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I am using this component but its showing always login page .http://localhost:3000/?_escaped_fragment_=/home/terms even I am setting this url in  whiteliste

Comment: Better to add your token too in step no. 3